# change label text from a VB6 binary (not source code)

Tags: user-interface, vb6, screen-scraping

we have a VB6 binary executable that comes with no source code. And we need to change the label text for that VB6 application from "AAA" to "BBB". Is there any way or tools that can do that?

The closest tool I can find right now is microsoft UISpy, it can read all the other elements but not the label.

I hope there is a tool that can change the resource in the .exe so that the label "AAA" will read "BBB". Or is it possible to write a wrapper application, it will launch the .exe, examine the application screen for "AAA" and change that to "BBB"?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of tampering with the EXE, it might be worth your while to simply write a simple wrapper that will run silently, obtaining the window handle after enumerating the VB6's parent window and directly modify it at run-time by hooking into VB6's window procedure looking for the handle of the label...

You could end up mistakenly rip out AAA which could be a binary for something else (by coincidence) and thereby breaking the application!...

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180996/sendmessage-pinvoke-keeps-crashing/2181092#2181092) for a similar question in which the SO was trying to modify an AOL window...and here's the direct [download](http://www.box.net/shared/4x4p9hpggc) for this demo application to obtain the text from an AOL window...this should give you a clue in the direction on how to find the window and enumerate it looking for label that has "AAA"

Comment: Be aware that the VB6 Label control does not have a window (no hWnd)

Answer (score 0):

What about hex-dumping it and searching for all instances of AAA?  Try replacing each one in succession with BBB and see if you win.

Comment: You are looking for a Unicode string: A.A.A. Also, be aware you might cause incorrect runtime behaviour by doing this.